# A trivial question regarding the supremum of a set

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Let $E$ be a subset of nonnegative real numbers. Suppose $E$ is bounded above and put $T = \{ x^2 : x \in E \}$. Say $\alpha = \sup E $. Then, $\alpha^2 = \sup T $.

#### Attempt:

Since $E$ is bounded above, the sup of $E$ exists. In fact, $x \leq \sup E = \alpha $ for all $ \in E$. Since $x \geq 0 $, it follows that $x^2 \leq \alpha^2 $. Hence, $\alpha^2 $ is an upper bound for the set $T$. To show it is the supremum of $T$, we have to prove that if $\beta < \alpha^2 $, then $\beta $ is not an upper bound of $T$. If this is false, then $x^2 \leq \beta $ for all $x \in E$. In particular, $x \leq \sqrt{ \beta } $. It follows that $\alpha \leq \sqrt{ \beta } $ since $x \in E$ was arbitrary. Hence, $\alpha^2 \leq \beta $. Contradiction.

I feel as is the last couple of sentences need maybe more justification or perhaps it is just wrong. I don't know. Hope you guys can help me with that.

Also, is this problem still holds if we say $E$  is a subset of all real numbers? MY answer is negative. Consider $E = \{ -2, -1 \} $. Then, $T = \{ 1, 4 \} $. Hence, $\sup E = -1 \implies ( \sup E )^2 = 1 \neq 4 = \sup T  $.

Comment: hint: under these conditions, $x \mapsto x^2$ is an increasing one-to-one function.

Comment: Your proof is correct!

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct for showing $\alpha^2$ is an upper bound for $T$

For showing  $\alpha^2$ is supremum of $T$

An easy way for me is:let $\beta $ be an upper bound of $T$ .To show $\beta\geq \alpha^2$

Now $\beta \geq x^2;x\in E$.Since $E$ is bounded above  hence it contains its supremum $\alpha$.
So $\beta \geq \alpha^2$.

If $E$ is not bounded above there is no guarantee that it will contain its supremum